# c++ paste value and print string

Tags: c++, paste, cout

I declare 2 string type strings, qhich is s, s1. I use s string with 'cin'
and I paste 3 values in s1. Then I print with 'cout' but it can't print string.

Here is my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main()

{

    string s,s1;
    cin>>s;
    s1[0]=s[1];
    s1[1]=s[2];
    s1[2]=s[3];
    s1[3]='\0';
    cout<<s1<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

s1 was not empty.... `cout<<s1[0]<<s1[1]<<s1[2]` and see.
Why s1 can't print?

Comment: `s1` is empty, `s1[0]` does not exist, therefore undefined behavior.

Comment: @nwp: Hi there! The comments section is for requesting clarification. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, the easiest way to accomplish OP's task is to use a library function like [substr()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) which takes care of all the details the posted code is missing (and already pointed out):

- memory management. The second string `s1` is empty, so trying to write its first four (unallocated) elements is undefined behavior. In general, `s1` should be resized to the needed length.
- null terminator. A `std::string` can manage it's internal representation and always returns a null-terminated string via its member functions [c_str](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) and [data](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) (since C++11).

That's how it could be done:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s;

    std::cin >> s;

    std::string s1;
    std::string::size_type start_pos = 1,
                           count = 3;
    if ( s.size() > start_pos )
        s1 = s.substr(start_pos, count);

    std::cout << s1 << '\n';
}
```

Comment: @SimonKraemer Good point. Looking at OP's code I think that they want to copy the three chars starting from posistion 1, so I guess that `s.substr(1,3);` would be a better fit.

Answer (score 0):

`s1` doesn't have any characters. You're trying to change the value of characters that do not exist.

Your program has undefined behaviour, and might just as easily open a llama zoo, reverse the polarity of the Earth's magnetic field, or solve cold fusion in the bath.

1. Make `s1` the correct size before writing things to it;
2. Don't write a `'\0'` to the end; this is not a C string; that is unnecessary. C++ strings look after themselves.

Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    std::string s, s1;
    std::cin >> s;

    assert(s.size() >= 4);
    s1.resize(3);

    s1[0] = s[1];
    s1[1] = s[2];
    s1[2] = s[3];

    std::cout << s1 << std::endl;
}
```

#### [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/edad56bb0aecdf8c)

Answer (score 0):

You can not assign as s1[0] = s[1]

Correct way is using assign function as:

```
string s,s1;
cin>>s;
s1.assign(s.begin()+1,s.begin()+4);
cout<<s1<<endl;
```

Comment: That's a good approach, though you should still check that there are enough characters in `s` first.

Comment: _"You can not assign as s1[0] = s[1]"_ You can, if `s1[0]` exists.

Comment: But in this case it does not exist, if it exist then s1[0] = s[1] is just the case of reassignment.

Comment: Right, which is what I said.

Answer (score 0):

String assignment cannot be done by assigning indexes without fixing or defining the size of the string. It may cause a string subscript error. If you want to do this, I think string concatenation is the best method; that is, by adding substrings or string indexes into string. I've given some code below that uses the string concatenation method.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string s,s1="";
    cin>>s;
    s1= s1 + s[1];
    s1= s1 + s[2];
    s1= s1 + s[3];
    cout<<s1<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should _explain_ the problem, and _explain_ the solution.

Comment: Edited! @BoundaryImposition

Comment: _"It may cause string subscript error"_ That is wrong; operator[] will not throw an exception in that case - you'll just have UB, overwriting memory and whatnot.